# Node JS very long process issue

Tags: node.js, process, exec, long-integer

I have one grunt file & one node js file which is doing build of my whole application. Currently I am running it like **node sample.js -mobile production** from command prompt & it is taking almost 15 mins. to finish but now I want to execute this command in node js script. so how can i do it? how can i get output after complete this long process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is basically this:

You want to execute a system command via node, and capture the standard output.

The best way to do that is using the `child_process` module:

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('node sample.js -mobile production', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('Process finished executing!');
  console.log('err:', err);
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  console.log('stderr:', stderr);
});
```

The example above shows you exactly what you'd do to get this working for your use case.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have tried this but it stopped before creating complete build 'cause it is taking almost 15 minutes to finish this build process so My concern is process should not terminate before finish build.

Comment: This won't stop running until your program has finished =) Even if it takes foreverrrr.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have apply settimeout for that & my problem is solved.